# MySite upgrade to 2013 - is it possible to do silent initialization for all users?

Tags: upgrade, mysite

We're upgrading a on premise farm to 2013. We've created a new MySite Host in the 2013 farm, and a new user profile service application. 
We have attached and upgraded the content database with the personal site collections, and run a script that adds the link to each users mysite to their user profile property.
When the users open MySite in 2013 they get a initiation dialog where they are asked to go social and use the new one drive for business. We have a lot of users, and need to do this initiation silently before the users log in. It is most important that we are able to run the one drive for business conversion that moves all the document libraries into folders in one drive. Does anyone know how this can be done programmatically/by script for all users after upgrade?

Regards ElinK